# Strange behavior with Process.Start and dfsdiag.exe

Tags: c#, .net, windows, microsoft-distributed-file-system

`DfsDiag.exe` is located by default in `C:\windows\system32`. I try to start a process for it with `Process.Start` but I always seem to get the error `The system cannot find the file specified`.
I don't seem to have the problem with anything else so far.

I tried...

- Specifying the full path `@"C:\Windows\System32\DfsDiag.exe"`
- Copying the file to the running directory.

The former failed while the latter worked. I can't for the life of me work out why.

(OS is Windows Server Standard 2008 R2)

Comment: 32-bit app? You've fallen foul of filesystem redirection. Try `C:\Windows\SysNative`.

Comment: **Never hard-code paths to system folders.** Not only is it good practice not to do so, but it also solves problems like this one.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe: Ah! it is a 32bit app running on a 64bit platform! Why not submit your comment as an answer.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe: Yes, that worked. I will have to remember that one. Please submit as answer so I can close this and award precious internet points.

Comment: @CodyGray the point is that it didn't work without the path _or_ with it.

Comment: And on a side note, the fact that the .NET Framework is still not aware of file system redirection after all these years, is really strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

32-bit app? You've fallen foul of filesystem redirection. Try C:\Windows\SysNative.