# Launching a file using Process.Start works, but adding conditions does not

Tags: c#, process.start

So I am trying to launch a printer script using cscript from C#, and cscript launches a visual basic file. So sort of a daisy chain (and I want to keep this daisy chain intact for certain reasons).

Here's the code:

```
Process.Start("c:/windows/system32/cscript.exe c:/windows/System32/Printing_Admin_Scripts/en-US/prnport.vbs");
```

Now, when I launch ONLY cscript, no problems.

However when I add the condition of prnport.vbs to the cscript launch, I get this error in Visual Studio:

```
"The system cannot find the file specified"
```

But I can confirm the file path is correct - `prnport.vbs` DOES exist in `/en-US`.

So what am I doing wrong here? Can you not pass arguments (and in this case, the file path is being passed as an argument to cscript.exe) when using Process.Start?

New to C# and confused about the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the arguments separately from the file to run. Try the [`Process.Start(string, string)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx):

```
Process.Start("c:/windows/system32/cscript.exe", 
    "c:/windows/System32/Printing_Admin_Scripts/en-US/prnport.vbs");
```

Comment: Exactly this. Since you have both files in the first parameter, it treats that whole string in quotations as one file argument - you have to remember that file names can have spaces.

Comment: If this is run on Windows Vista or later, will file system redirection be a concern?  I only ask because the script is in \windows\system32.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway The real problem would be running a 32-bit process from a 64-bit OS, in which case you'll want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585873/strange-behavior-with-process-start-and-dfsdiag-exe

Answer (score 1):

That's an Argument, you'll need to use another overload of `Process.Start`

Have a look at the [method's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

`Process.Start (String, String)` will do, others are possible and offer more flexibility, if you should need that, too.

Answer (score 1):

The `Process.Start` expects the file name as the first parameter. The arguments are given in separate argument.